# NEO4j / Cyhper pairing nodes based on String and Array

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two node types: `:Areas` and `:SavedSearch`, that I would like to get pairs of in order to bulk set relationships.

Areas have a name property like this:

```
(a:Area {Name: "A1232"})
```

Saved Searches have an Areas property like this:

```
(ss:SavedSearch {Areas: ["A6473", "A1232", "A4568"]})
```

I have tried variations on the following query but it doesn't seem to work:

```
MATCH (a:Area) with a MATCH (ss:SavedSearch)
with a, ss
where a.Name in ss.Areas
return a.Name, ss.Areas
```

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Why not having relationships between Areas and SavedSearch instead of the array property ?

Comment: That is the intention of this query - to provide the starting point to bulk create those relationships. If there is an easier way to create the relationships I would love to know though! The relationships are just missing from an initial data load and will be created on the fly as new saved searches are added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok then, something like that should works:

```
MATCH (ss:SavedSearch {Areas: ["A6473", "A1232", "A4568"]})
UNWIND ss.Areas as area
MATCH (a:Area{Name: area})
MERGE (a)-[:LINKED_TO]->(ss)
```

Comment: Thank you! That has worked marvellously! And I will definitely look into the documentation to get a better understanding of UNWIND which from the above seems very powerful.